# How to use a string as variable name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable having same name as a string. Using the string, how can the access the value stored in the variable of the same name?

I wanted to do the following thing:

```
A1=10

A2=20


var1='A1'

var2='A1+A2'


print(var1) #I want output to be 10

print(var2) #I want output to be 30

print(var1) gives 'A1'

print(var2) gives 'A1+A2'
```

Comment: If you want `print(var2)` to output `30`, that's not using `'A1+A2'` as a variable name... that's *evaluating a string as code*, which is an entirely different question.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary if you want strings rather than variables to refer to values?

Answer (score -1):

```
A1=10

A2=20


var1='A1'

var2='A2'
print(var1) #I want output to be 10

print(var2) #I want output to be 30

print (globals()[var1] +globals()[var2])
```